# How to use routerLink relative to its parent with a named outlet?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

Angular 13.2.2

I have a named route that is nested under another named route with a module that is lazy loaded. The routes look like this.

app.routing

```
{
    path: 'active',
    outlet: 'editor',
    loadChildren: () => import('./editor/editor.module').then(m => m.EditorModule),
},
```

editor.routing

```
{
    path: '',
    component: EditorComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'a',
        outlet: 'subbar',
        component: AComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'b',
        outlet: 'subbar',
        component: BComponent
      }
    ]
}
```

The links are being generated dynamically so I am setting my `routerLinks` programmatically like this:

`this.url = [ { outlets: { 'subbar': button.url } } ]` where `button.url` is either `a` or `b`. So I end up with two buttons that have links to `a` and `b`.

and then

`[routerLink]='url'`

First I navigate to `(editor:active)`, and my button links look like `http://localhost:4200/home(editor:active/(subbar:a))` and same for `b`. This is correct.

The first time I go to one of the links, it works correctly and navigates to

`(editor:active/(subbar:a))`

But then the link to b shows `http://localhost:4200/home(editor:active/(subbar:/(a//subbar:b)))` which of course is a route that doesn't exist.

If I change things to use `router.navigate(this.url, { relativeTo: this.route.parent })` then it works. What is interesting is that everything was fine without lazy loading, but when I switched to lazy loading the `editor` module, it introduced this problem.

I have tried adding `'..'` and `'../'` to the routerLink but it makes no positive difference. How can I replicate what `router.navigate` is doing with the `relativeTo` attribute on a `routerLink`?

Comment: Facing this exact issue, did you find a solution? If I find something, I'll post it here.

Comment: Not exactly, but I settled for a workaround. I'll post an answer with the details.

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work, I had to change how the routing config was set up, but I think it partially defeats the point of lazy loading, just not sure how much.

Change the child routes file to be like this, removing the parent component and leaving the children.

```
// editor.routing
routes = [
      {
        path: 'a',
        outlet: 'subbar',
        component: AComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'b',
        outlet: 'subbar',
        component: BComponent
      }
    ]
}
```

And the main route to be like this.

```
//app.routing
{
  path: 'active',
  outlet: 'editor',
  loadChildren: () =>
    import('./editor/editor.module').then((m) => m.EditorModule),
  component: EditorComponent, // <- Add Component Here
}
```

Comment: Cheers for sharing. My issue was not so much to do with lazy loading, but I was seeing exactly the same behaviour as you. So far my only fix has been to provide an absolute path in the routerLink, but that is not ideal as it requires child modules to have knowledge of parent route paths, unless I pass it down to them, which complicates the code.